# Service worker communicate to clients

Tags: client, service-worker

I have been trying to send messages to clients from service worker but if I use

```
self.clients.matchAll()
.then((clients) => {
  clients.forEach(function(client) {
    client.postMessage({msg: 'Hello from SW'})
  })
})
```

it won't send to any client even if I have a tab open in the browser, but if I send a message from the **client** to the **service worker**

```
// client
navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage({title: 'Send message from client'})
```

and in the service worker

```
self.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
  self.clients.fetchAll()
    .then((clients) => {
      clients.forEach(function(client) {
        client.postMessage({msg: 'Hello from SW'})
     })
  })
})
```

it can send a message and finds clients.
what am I doing wrong?, should I use indexedDB instead?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I don't believe that `clients.fetchAll()` exists. You probably mean `clients.matchAll()`, which should give you the behavior you describe:

```js
self.clients.matchAll().then(clients => {
    clients.forEach(client => client.postMessage({msg: 'Hello from SW'}));
})
```

A nicer alternative allowing the service worker to communicate with clients, while avoiding having to send messages one-by-one, is to [make use of the Broadcast Channel API](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/09/broadcastchannel). It is now supported in recent versions of Chrome as well as in Firefox.

```js
// From service-worker.js:
const channel = new BroadcastChannel('sw-messages');
channel.postMessage({title: 'Hello from SW'});

// From your client pages:
const channel = new BroadcastChannel('sw-messages');
channel.addEventListener('message', event => {
    console.log('Received', event.data);
});
```

Comment: You are right about the self.clients.matchAll, I have used that, the API of the Broadcast Channel works really nice. Thanks.

Comment: thanks man BroadcastChannel worked for me, but when we are doing  client.postMessage we should be able to catch response in page using below code right?navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('message', function(event) { console.log('Received a message from service worker: ', event.data); });    
 why isnt this code working?

Comment: @3bu1 Were you able to find an answer for the question in your comment?

Comment: I used that as well. But I was just wondering if you ever got client.postMessage working

Comment: BroadcastChannel does not work in Safari :( I've got v14

Comment: client.postMessage works for me. Agree with @t1gor, broadcastChannel has worse browser compatibility compared to SW. `postMessage` should be the API to use if you care about Safari.

Comment: From the API doc, seems it should be this: `channel.onmessage = function(e) {
  console.log('Received', e.data);
};`

Answer (score 6):

Adding `includeUncontrolled` option should do:

```
for (const client of await clients.matchAll({includeUncontrolled: true, type: 'window'})) {
  client.postMessage(message);
}
```